# Cascading dropdown list sends ajax request but doesn't return required html and data PHP

Tags: php, ajax, dropdown

I've been working on cascading drop downs( using php / Ajax ) where the second drop-down values are dependent on the first one, I've done what is supposed to be necessary but it doesn't seem to work, i will post my code below, and would appreciate a good eye or some helpful tips:

This is my first drop-down with correct locations got from database :

```
    <?php 
$sql1 = "SELECT location_Id,location_Name FROM locations  "; 
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1); ?>  
             <?php while ($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $row1['location_Id'] ; ?>"> <?php echo $row1['location_Name'] ; ?> </option>             
     <?php } ?> </select>
```

**And my second drop-down that needs to be populated depending on first :**

**My script :**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function get_states() { // Call to ajax function
    var location_Id = $('#location').val();
    var dataString = "location_Id="+location_Id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.10/skylite/gethosp", // Name of the php files
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#hospital").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**And my other php page/code that is being called from Ajax's request :**

```
 <?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if(isset($_POST['location_Id'])) {
      $sql = "select * from hospitals where location_Id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location_Id']);
      $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        echo "<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>";
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
          echo "<option value='".$row['hospital_Id']."'>".$row['hospital_Name']."</option>";
        }
      }
    } else {
      header('http://192.168.0.10/skylite/Claims');
    }  
?>
```

The problem is when i choose a location from the first dropdown, the ajax request is being sent (`onclick="get_states();"`) with correct variable and id, but second dropdown is still not being populated
[image]

Comment: if you console.log HTML what do u get?

Comment: Using your debugger, check what is the raw response of your Ajax call. Post us the result

Comment: just an advice, don't mix codes, use php to return pure array/object and inside JS loop over thm and append options

Comment: consider adding an error function to your ajax call, should have been first thing to try when it doesn't work

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan i will edit my code and post it

Comment: @Lalati I saw your edit. But I was looking forward to see the raw ajax response. It is may be dirty for some reason.

Comment: @Kaddath would there be an error if the variable is being sent and shown under param for XHR requests ? i've posted an image with the request parameters

Comment: Yes it can, even if the response code is 200, there can be a decoding error due to format for example

Comment: @ِAllloush Hello, if i console.log(html) i get all the page back in console without the body, so it's only the navigation menu, side bar etc. with no body, i removed my 2nd dropdown select and replaced with <div id="hospital"></div> to append html there , i get back <---- SELECT ---- > and the output as the page itself with error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @Kaddath Hey, i got the result but as the page without the body, and in the body the text result, i will post an image

Answer (score 0):

You have do it on onchange event not on click.

```
onclick="get_states()";
```

replace

```
onchange="get_states()";
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Execuse me, my code had on change and not onclick, miss typed here

Comment: Can you show what response you are getting on the ajax?

Comment: i got the result, but since gethosp is a controller, and because i'm using MVC and getting header/nav/footer dynamically, the result is being the header + nav bar + footer + the dropdown i need with its values

Comment: You have to theme it for only options that you have made in the code and put `exit()` or `die()` under while loop. this will work.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you mentioned in your comment, the error is in your PHP file. So the result that you get as `html` is the PHP error page or the beginning or your output with a error message, if you have a full page as an answer, that's why.

The reason is because you are using `mysqli_fetch_object` which gets each row as a PHP object, not an array.

You are then supposed to acces the properties like this

```
echo "<option value='".$row->hospital_Id."'>".$row->hospital_Name."</option>";
```

Comment: Hello, yes i figured that out, so either fetch array and use $row[''], or if object $row->hospital_Id, but now i got the result inside my header + navigation bar + side bar because the page i m posting to is a controller in my mvc architecture

Comment: sorry your last comment is not clear, i can only answer to problems i have the infos about... I don't have the HTML part where `#hospital` is defined, nor which MVC structure you are using. And your last sentence adds a confusion between page and controller, so i would need more informations, or maybe that would be a different question than this one.